# Facebook library not exporting to android .apk

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse, sdk

I have an Android app that allows users to login via Facebook. Everything works well in the emulator, but when I export a signed .apk, and run from my phone, it appears that the Facebook SDK isn't included (it will flash an empty FB screen for a second, then go back to the previous screen).

The facebook SDK is un-compiled and the code is included in the project as a separate package. As I said in above, it works in an emulator so I'm assuming I properly included the package as a library from my own package.

Is there anything special you need to do to include an outside library when exporting the .apk?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the Facebook SDK isn't included?  I think the problem is likely something different.  Have you tried debugging on your phone?

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that it could be something else. I just kind of got thrown into Android development last week so I'm not sure how to debug on my phone... could you point me to a tutorial by chance?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, it does a pretty good job of making it simple for you.  If not, I'd look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html.  You should be able to find an eclipse tutorial from that page too.

Comment: For simple answer to your question, it is no. It would help us a lot if you could provide logcat… Quick use: `adb logcat -c` to clear logs, and `adb logcat -d` to dump new logs.